# Is this automaton correct for this regular laguage?

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

The language in question is given by the regular expression $ab^*a$.

[image]

Comment: It’s correct, but it’s more complicated than necessary: you could remove state $q_2$ and put a $b$ loop at $q_1$. (By the way, *automata* is plural. The singular is *automaton*: one automaton, several automata.)

Comment: Should I add a state in which if there are any characters after the final a, the string goes to a dead state? Because now wouldnt it recognize strings that have that pattern but may end differently?

Comment: Yes, if you want a fully described deterministic automaton, and you should also have a $b$ transition from $q_0$ to the dead state.